# Modify keycloak default realm on administrative console url

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

On keycloak when you are trying to access the administrative console, it goes to a url `https://<domain>/admin/master/console/`. Which the `master` on the url is the default realm
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL8Bn.png)

Is there a way to modify the realm name on the URL? I want to modify the realm name to use a custom realm that has been created before. So it will looks like `https://<domain>/admin/<custom-realm>/console/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, for example, create your own custom "welcome" theme and add boxes with your realm specific URLs to the index.ftl.

See the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#configuring-a-theme) for more details.

Note that it says:

> All theme types, except welcome, are configured through the Admin Console.

and later...

> Change the welcome theme by using the spi-theme-welcome-theme option.

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --spi-theme-welcome-theme=custom-theme
```

A code example:

```
<div class="welcome-primary-link">
    <h3><a href="${adminUrl}"><img src="welcome-content/user.png">Administration Console
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h3>
    <div class="description">
        Centrally manage all aspects of the ${productNameFull} server
    </div>
</div>

<div class="welcome-primary-link">
    <h3><a href="${adminUrl}yourownrealm/console/"><img src="welcome-content/user.png">Your own Realm Console
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h3>
    <div class="description">
        Centrally manage all aspects at your own realm of the ${productNameFull} server
    </div>
</div>
```